# Docker REST API is not binding on port for Jenkins

Tags: rest, jenkins, docker, jenkins-plugins

I am using :
**docker version: 1.11.1, build 5604cbe** . I have made entries in `/etc/default/docker` as follows to configure REST API of docker for jenkins user group :

```
    # Use DOCKER_OPTS to modify the daemon startup options.
    #DOCKER_OPTS="--dns 8.8.8.8 --dns 8.8.4.4"

    DOCKER_OPTS="G- jenkins -H unix://var/run/docker.sock -H tcp://0.0.0.0:9090"

    export DOCKER_HOST="tcp://0.0.0.0:9090"
```

---

ps- I have also tried with **127.0.0.1**

Then I did `sudo service docker restart`

command `$ ps aux|grep docker`  returned:

```
root     12385  0.0  0.2 421840 36016 ?        Ssl  19:21   0:00 /usr/bin/docker daemon -H fd://
root     12391  0.0  0.0 294652 12188 ?        Ssl  19:21   0:00 docker-containerd -l /var/run/docker/libcontainerd/docker-containerd.sock --runtime docker-runc
root     12654  0.0  0.0  21296  1028 pts/1    S+   19:28   0:00 grep --color=auto docker
```

Seems like The **REST API** is not getting bind to **port:9090**.

Then I am **using Jenkins Docker build step plugin** to connect with docker REST API. It returns following :

---

```
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Telco_automated_build/workspace
[Docker] INFO: Pulling image registry.hub.docker.com/pratyush/product:latest
ERROR: Build step failed with exception
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to 127.0.0.1:9090 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused
    at org.glassfish.jersey.apache.connector.ApacheConnector.apply(ApacheConnector.java:513)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:246)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:667)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:664)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:424)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:664)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:424)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.post(JerseyInvocation.java:333)
    at com.github.dockerjava.jaxrs.PullImageCmdExec.execute(PullImageCmdExec.java:37)
    at com.github.dockerjava.jaxrs.PullImageCmdExec.execute(PullImageCmdExec.java:17)
    at com.github.dockerjava.jaxrs.AbstrDockerCmdExec.exec(AbstrDockerCmdExec.java:57)
    at com.github.dockerjava.core.command.AbstrDockerCmd.exec(AbstrDockerCmd.java:29)
    at com.github.dockerjava.core.command.PullImageCmdImpl.exec(PullImageCmdImpl.java:15)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.dockerbuildstep.cmd.PullImageCommand.execute(PullImageCommand.java:75)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.dockerbuildstep.DockerBuilder.perform(DockerBuilder.java:75)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
```

At the **jenkins global setting** when i hit **test-connection** it returns:

```
Something went wrong, cannot connect to http://127.0.0.1:9090/, cause: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to 127.0.0.1:9090 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused
```

PS- I have **restarted Jenkins server** after changing global setting.

Any help, where am I missing ?

Comment: Can you curl to the Rest API from the Host?

Comment: No. It is returning **failed to connect. connection refused**.  I am using ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu 16.04 uses systemd now I believe. In which case the `docker daemon` arguments are not set using `/etc/default/docker`. You can see they're not being picked up in the output of your `$ ps aux|grep docker`.

Instead you need to [follow the instructions](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/systemd/) to set daemon args in systemd-based setups.

Comment: Thanks a lot @jharris